# How Firebase RemoteConfig add key value for different app flavors

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

How to add different value for same parameter for different flavor of android app.

I have debug, release and mock apps, all have different package name, and they are added as different app in Firebase Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create Condition on the parameter and select App ID and package name. This will allow to add different value for different package. See attached screenshots!

[image]

[image]